# Installing Samba on a Separate Volume (Hard Disk)

Tags: system-installation, samba

I have managed to get my first Ubuntu Server (minimal) setup up and running on a 1GB internal USB header stick.

What I need to do now is to install the file server, but on a separate physical disk (500GB), including the configuration files. Is there a way to do this?

I cannot use the apt-get functions because I have deployed a minimal install, as a normal install won't fit on the boot volume.

(I'm new to Ubuntu Server, so I would appreciate that complex-talk be kept to a minimum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need to install Samba from source though. [See the Samba manual](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch02.html), chapter 2 deals with this. From the link:

> In addition, Table 2-1 shows some other parameters that you can give the configure script if you wish to store parts of the Samba distribution in different places, perhaps to make use of multiple disks or partitions. Note that the defaults sometimes refer to a prefix specified earlier in the table.

[image]

Comment: Do I need to use a specific compiler though? Or is there one that can make it easy to compile it with only a small amount of knowledge? The only one I have is Visual Studio 2005 (the computer I'm using to manage this server).

Comment: No you need to compile samba from source. See "Binary or Source?" in the link in the answer. It has step by step instructions on compiling samba from source.